# NPE in spark with Joda DateTime

Tags: apache-spark, jodatime

When executing simple mapping in spark on joda DateTime field I am receving NullPointerException.

Code snippet:

```
val me1 = (accountId, DateTime.now())
val me2 = (accountId, DateTime.now())
val me3 = (accountId, DateTime.now())
val rdd = spark.parallelize(List(me1, me2, me3))

val result = rdd.map{case (a,d) => (a,d.dayOfMonth().roundFloorCopy())}.collect.toList
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.joda.time.DateTime$Property.roundFloorCopy(DateTime.java:2280)
    at x.y.z.jobs.info.AggJobTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AggJobTest.scala:47)
    at x.y.z.jobs.info.AggJobTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AggJobTest.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:780)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:780)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1314)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1314)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Update:
In ordeer to reproduce the problem you need to use KryoSerializer:

> .set("spark.serializer",
>   "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem (Scala 2.10.4, Spark 1.4.1, Joda Time 2.8.2) with a code you've provided. Could you provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some configuration details?

Comment: I experienced the same using DayOfMonth, MonthOfYear, etc... it seems it was missing some Calendar info on workers. I ended up to build a simple date case class MyDate(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int). That was enough for my target.

Comment: @zero323 I use Scala 2.10.5, Spark 1.2.0, Joda Time 2.7. I notice that it is important to use KryoSerializer in order to reproduce  the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have pointed out, you are using the KryoSerializer with the Joda DateTime object. It appears that the serialization has left out some required information, you may wish to look at using one of the projects which adds support for Joda DateTime objects to Kryo. For example https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers provides a serializer called `JodaDateTimeSerializer` which you could register with `kryo.register( DateTime.class, new JodaDateTimeSerializer() );`