# How do I use joda.time in flink (or how do I use typeutils.runtime.kryo)

Tags: serialization, jodatime, kryo, apache-flink

In a flink project I use a case class click.

```
case class click( date: LocalDateTime, stbId:String, channelId :Int)
```

This class populated DataSets and it worked fine with the date being a java 8 `java.time.LocalDateTime`. After switching to org.joda (version2.9) in a java 7 environment calls to the click Objects in the DataSets did not perform as previously. Access to certain functions of the date field of a click Object threw `NullPointerExceptions`. Example of those functions are `getHourOfDay` `toString`, etc. I was able to assure that the date field of the click class was not null. 
I suspect that the joda time library does not interact well with kryo serialization. See [joda DateTime format cause null pointer error in spark RDD functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890375/joda-datetime-format-cause-null-pointer-error-in-spark-rdd-functions) or [NPE in spark with Joda DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256318/npe-in-spark-with-joda-datetime/32259597?s=2|0.2585#32259597)
In the Flink API there is org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.Serializers with the static method `registerJodaTime`. That seems to be relevant. I simple mindedly tried

```
import  org.apache.flink.api.common._
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo._
Serializers.registerJodaTime(new ExecutionConfig)
```

That did not suffice.
Am I right in this? How do I use java.typeutils.runtime.kryo?

Version used Flink:  0.9.1. scala : 2.10  joda.time 2.9

**Follow up:**
Here is the exact added code as proposed (thanks to Fabian and Robert)

```
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
//import  org.apache.flink.api.common._
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo._
Serializers.registerJodaTime(env.getConfig)
```

In the log files of an embedded execution I could find the following relevant parts:

```
16:44:53,998 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - The job has 2 registered types and 0 default Kryo serializers
16:44:53,998 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo types: 
16:44:53,998 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo with Serializers types: 
16:44:53,998 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo with Serializer Classes types: Entry{k=class org.joda.time.DateTime, v=class de.javakaffee.kryoserializers.jodatime.JodaDateTimeSerializer},Entry{k=class org.joda.time.Interval, v=class de.javakaffee.kryoserializers.jodatime.JodaIntervalSerializer}
16:44:53,998 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo default Serializers: 
16:44:53,998 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo default Serializers Classes 
16:44:53,998 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered POJO types: 
16:44:53,998 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Static code analysis mode: DISABLE
16:44:54,545 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                  - Slf4jLogger started
16:44:54,560 DEBUG akka.event.EventStream                                        - logger log1-Slf4jLogger started
....
16:44:57,103 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor             - class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime does not contain a getter for field iLocalMillis
16:44:57,103 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor             - class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime does not contain a setter for field iLocalMillis
16:44:57,103 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor                 - class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime is not a valid POJO type
16:44:57,275 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$                        - accessedFields: Map()
16:44:57,369 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - The job has 2 registered types and 0 default Kryo serializers
16:44:57,369 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo types: 
16:44:57,369 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo with Serializers types: 
16:44:57,369 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo with Serializer Classes types: Entry{k=class org.joda.time.DateTime, v=class de.javakaffee.kryoserializers.jodatime.JodaDateTimeSerializer},Entry{k=class org.joda.time.Interval, v=class de.javakaffee.kryoserializers.jodatime.JodaIntervalSerializer}
16:44:57,369 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo default Serializers: 
16:44:57,369 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo default Serializers Classes 
16:44:57,369 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered POJO types: 
16:44:57,369 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Static code analysis mode: DISABLE
```

Nevertheless I witnessed the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.isSupported(LocalDateTime.java:625)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$PaddedNumber.printTo(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1435)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$Composite.printTo(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2474)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.printTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:655)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.print(DateTimeFormatter.java:709)
    at org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.toString(LocalDateTime.java:2087)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at scala.runtime.StringAdd$.$plus$extension(StringAdd.scala:13)
    at myflink.click.toString(Ingestor.scala:20)
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, this line `Serializers.registerJodaTime(new ExecutionConfig)` the right method call, but it does not have any effects because its not the execution config from the ExecutionEnvironment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flink is using [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) for types it can not serialize. `LocalDateTime` is such a class.

Sadly, Kryo is also not able to properly serialize it, so we have to tell Kryo how to do it by giving it a specialized serializer for this class.

1. Add `de.javakaffee:kryo-serializers` as a dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.javakaffee</groupId>
    <artifactId>kryo-serializers</artifactId>
    <version>0.30</version>
</dependency>
```

(please note that adding this dependency might cause problems using Flink on a cluster. Please let me know)

2. Register the new serializer with the `ExecutionEnvironment`:

```scala
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(classOf[LocalDateTime], classOf[JodaLocalDateTimeSerializer])
```

I hope that helps (I'm keeping the old answer as a reference)

---

**Some general remarks for debugging Kryo/Serializer issues in Flink:**

When executing the job locally (should also work in the `./bin/flink` frontend, but then the output is probably in the log/ directory), you should see something like:

```
14:05:52,863 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - The job has 15 registered types and 2 default Kryo serializers 
14:05:52,943 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster         - Starting FlinkMiniCluster. 
14:05:53,150 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                  - Slf4jLogger started
```

With the number of registered types and Kryo serializers higher than 0.

With DEBUG log level (replace `INFO` with `DEBUG` in the `log4j.properties`) you can actually get even more detailed information about the registered serializers:

```
14:10:39,935 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo types: 
14:10:39,935 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo with Serializers types: 
14:10:39,935 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo with Serializer Classes types: 
14:10:39,935 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo default Serializers: 
14:10:39,935 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered Kryo default Serializers Classes 
14:10:39,935 DEBUG org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - Registered POJO types:
```

Comment: I added some relevant log output. One needs to read after "Follow Up".

Comment: Can you share the full source code of the job you are running? Or maybe a minimal example to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 3):

You should register the joda serializers in the `ExecutionConfig` of the `ExecutionEnvironment`:

```
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
Serializers.registerJodaTime(env.getConfig());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That definitely looks like a more promising approach. However trying the code fragment out still produces the NPE. Do you suspect some other issue?